# inserting value into forgein key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I am kind of a newbie when it comes to SQL so you might find my question silly, but I've honestly searched the web for an answer but when I tried to implement it to my code it did not work.

So I am trying to insert value from a variable into a SQL table that has two foreign keys, and two integers.

so this is the code I have:

```
$skovalg = $_POST{"sko"};
$strvalg = $_POST{"str"};
$firmavalg = $_POST{"firma"};
$antallvalg = $_POST{"antall"};

  $select = "insert into sport-bestilling(skoid, firmaid, str, antall) values ('$skovalg', '$strvalg', '$firmavalg', '$antallvalg')";
$sql = mysql_query($select);
```

`skoid` and `firmaid` are the foreign keys ,`str` and `antall` are integers.

all of the variables is a number and the number within the foreign keys are within the right range.

`sport-bestilling` is the table name.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I do not gett any that's why it is so hard to figure out

Comment: Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to insert a foreign key into a table, you must insert the value of the key that is contained in the table to which the constraint is mapped.

When inserting foreign key values it is best practice not to insert them manually via an insert into values() statement, but to insert into with a subquery that selects the primary key and values from the table you're mapping to. That way you will only ever insert mapped keys. Here's an example.

```
Insert into TableWithFK (ForeignKeyId, FooValues)
Select PrimaryKeyId, FooValues from TableWithPK
Where PrimaryKeyId = 1234
```

In this case, I'm assuming that there is a Primary Key in the TableWithPK table valued at 1234.